# Higher Dimensional Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is somewhat of a vague question, and I think I already know the answer is no, but I'd like to be convinced with a solid example or at least gain some insight.  Anyway, I'm wondering the following

Can any distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$ can be "naturally" extended to a distribution function on  $\mathbb{R}^n $.

I know this is certainly the case for the Uniform, Normal, and Geometric distributions.  I've seen some sketchy stuff about the Poisson that makes me think it also works, but I'm not sure. I also don't even really have a definition of natural.  Maybe I could have some help with this as well?

Comment: You can just take the (outer) product. This corresponds to looking at $n$ independent copies of the original probability distribution.